# Odata : Get data from Salesforce Using Odata?

Tags: odata, salesforce-connect

Is there any way to get Salesforce data (Lead,Contact) using Odata. There are some Application Cloud Drivers, Progress DataDirect Cloud and Skyvia Connect for it. Are they using Normal Rest Api and then converting Data to Odata?

Answer (score 0):

[Progress DataDirect Cloud](https://www.progress.com/data-connectivity/odata-salesforce-lightning-connect) exposes the external data sources as standard OData for consumption by Salesforce Connect independent of Salesforce REST APIs. For example, if it's an on-premises hadoop cluster or SQL database, the service will translate database queries into OData and work with, or independently, from your firewall configuration. Beyond the OData standard, it supports specific features optimized for Salesforce Connect to optimize access to external sources.